# Check if apscheduler cron task successful

Tags: python, linux, apscheduler

I am trying to execute a cron task on a cloud server.

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

# Schedule the downloadData function to run every day at 4 (AM)
scheduler.add_job(downloadData, trigger="cron", hour=4, minute=30)
    
# Start the scheduler
scheduler.start()
```

If for some reason, the server is down, then that cron task wont execute, and it will wait for the next day to execute again.

But is there a way to check if that job actually executed at the desired time and day?

Comment: As hakanhan points out in his answer the only reliable solution is for your job to log that it ran to completion. That doesn't necessarily mean a text log file but simply relying on interrogating the scheduler that it started the job is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

On the task itself you could add some code that would output a successful message to a log file somewhere on your server.
That way, if the cron task is successful you will be able to see it on the log file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add logging statements within the **downloadData** function to indicate when it starts and completes its execution. This way, you can check the log files to see if the function was triggered at the expected time. Optionally you may trigger email to notify the same within the function.